# How to increment a vector in AVX/AVX2

Tags: assembly, x86, simd, intrinsics, avx2

I want to use intrinsics to increment the elements of a SIMD vector. The simplest way seems to be to add 1 to each element, like this:

(note: `vec_inc` has been set to 1 before)

```c
vec = _mm256_add_epi16 (vec, vec_inc);
```

But is there any special instruction to increment a vector, similar to [`inc`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_arithmetic_instructions.htm)? Or is there any other easier way?

Comment: No, there's no special instruction - just  add a vector of 1s, as you suggest above.

Comment: Subtracting `-1` can be cheaper, as a vector of `set1(-1)` can be generated on the fly instead of loading, with `vpcmpeqd ymm0, ymm0, ymm0`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `INC` instruction is not a SIMD level instruction, it operates on integer scalars.
As you and Paul already suggested, the simplest way is to add `1` to each vector element, which you can do by adding a vector of `1`s.

If you want to simulate an intrinsic, you can implement your own function:

```
inline __m256i _mm256_inc_epi16(__m256i a)
{
    return _mm256_add_epi16(a, _mm256_set1_epi16(1));
}
```

---

For similar questions on x86 intrinsics in the future, you can find the collection of Intel ISA intrinsics at [Intel's Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide). Also see the extensive resources documented under the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) and [sse](/questions/tagged/sse) tag info:

- [x86 tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)
- [sse tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info)

Comment: I have eaten `Intel Instrinsics Guide`. By the way I will accept the answer

Comment: If you're still hungry after eating the Intel Intrinsics Guide, do be sure to check out the resources in the [tag:x86] tag wiki. :-) @fac I added that to the answer for future users, too.

Comment: @CodyGray: There are also a couple SSE/AVX intrinsics tutorial type things in the [SSE tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info).  The x86 tag wiki mentions this (at the top), but I suspect most people won't notice that.