# How does SSE scalar code outperform AVX vector code

Tags: c++, g++, vectorization, avx2

I'm doing simple packed additions for doubles to compare performance of scalar and packed data on linux with haswell processor.

Testing function:

```
struct vector {
     __m256d v; // double v[3];
     // ctor
     vector operator+(const vector& rhs) const {
         return v + rhs.v;
     }
};
vector f(vector* varray, vector* varray2) {
    // varray and varray2 are two arrays of vectors of length 128
    vector ret;
    for (unsigned j = 0; j != 10000000; ++j) {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i != 128; ++i) {
            ret = ret + varray[i] + varray2[i];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The following are `f` compiled with `-march=native -O2` (trailing nop omitted) *I've verified that main function directly `call` f*

```
  400560:   c5 f9 57 c0             vxorpd xmm0,xmm0,xmm0
  400564:   4c 8d 56 18             lea    r10,[rsi+0x18]
  400568:   4c 8d 4a 18             lea    r9,[rdx+0x18]
  40056c:   48 89 f8                mov    rax,rdi
  40056f:   41 b8 80 96 98 00       mov    r8d,0x989680
  400575:   c5 f9 28 c8             vmovapd xmm1,xmm0
  400579:   c5 f9 28 d0             vmovapd xmm2,xmm0
  40057d:   48 81 c6 00 0c 00 00    add    rsi,0xc00
  400584:   0f 1f 40 00             nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
  400588:   4c 89 d2                mov    rdx,r10
  40058b:   4c 89 c9                mov    rcx,r9
  40058e:   66 90                   xchg   ax,ax
  400590:   c5 eb 58 12             vaddsd xmm2,xmm2,QWORD PTR [rdx];***
  400594:   48 83 c2 18             add    rdx,0x18
  400598:   c5 eb 58 11             vaddsd xmm2,xmm2,QWORD PTR [rcx];***
  40059c:   48 83 c1 18             add    rcx,0x18
  4005a0:   c5 f3 58 4a f0          vaddsd xmm1,xmm1,QWORD PTR [rdx-0x10];***
  4005a5:   c5 fb 58 42 f8          vaddsd xmm0,xmm0,QWORD PTR [rdx-0x8];***
  4005aa:   c5 f3 58 49 f0          vaddsd xmm1,xmm1,QWORD PTR [rcx-0x10];***
  4005af:   c5 fb 58 41 f8          vaddsd xmm0,xmm0,QWORD PTR [rcx-0x8];***
  4005b4:   48 39 d6                cmp    rsi,rdx
  4005b7:   75 d7                   jne    400590 <f(vector*, vector*)+0x30>
  4005b9:   41 83 e8 01             sub    r8d,0x1
  4005bd:   75 c9                   jne    400588 <f(vector*, vector*)+0x28>
  4005bf:   c5 fb 11 10             vmovsd QWORD PTR [rax],xmm2
  4005c3:   c5 fb 11 48 08          vmovsd QWORD PTR [rax+0x8],xmm1
  4005c8:   c5 fb 11 40 10          vmovsd QWORD PTR [rax+0x10],xmm0
  4005cd:   c3                      ret
```

While for vector code there's two simple `vaddpd`:

```
  4005d0:   ba 80 96 98 00          mov    edx,0x989680
  4005d5:   c5 f9 57 c0             vxorpd xmm0,xmm0,xmm0
  4005d9:   0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
  4005e0:   b8 20 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x20
  4005e5:   0f 1f 00                nop    DWORD PTR [rax]
  4005e8:   c5 fd 58 04 07          vaddpd ymm0,ymm0,YMMWORD PTR [rdi+rax*1];***
  4005ed:   c5 fd 58 04 06          vaddpd ymm0,ymm0,YMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax*1];***
  4005f2:   48 83 c0 20             add    rax,0x20
  4005f6:   48 3d 00 10 00 00       cmp    rax,0x1000
  4005fc:   75 ea                   jne    4005e8 <f(vector*, vector*)+0x18>
  4005fe:   83 ea 01                sub    edx,0x1
  400601:   75 dd                   jne    4005e0 <f(vector*, vector*)+0x10>
  400603:   c3                      ret
```

And the performance is:

```
real    0m1.971s // sd
real    0m2.126s // pd
```

Anyway, after a lot of observations, timed with `time`, the scalar version is nearly always (90%+) faster than packed one.

Querying the Agner's table, `vaddpd` and `vaddsd` has exactly the same latency and throughput, then what's the reason that three `vaddsd` are even faster than a single `vaddpd`? (Or where shall I focus on to figure out the limiting spot?)

*I know there's a few thing that can improve the (testing) code, e.g. unrolling, yet that's delibrately done in order to compare single vector and single scalar instruction performance.*

Comment: It is unclear what **exactly** you timed there.  It isn't just those instructions; and context will probably help.

Comment: @Yakk, Thanks, please my appended test function.

Comment: @PaulR, You mean the vector class? Added just now.

Comment: Your generated vector code has a serial dependency on `ymm0`, and since `vaddpd` has a latency of 3 cycles on Haswell (4 on Skylake) it's going to be far from optimal. The SSE code interleaves instructions with dependencies (alternating between operations on `xmm0` and `xmm1`).

Comment: @PaulR, Yeah, but it's not intended to be optimal. It's intended just to compare the performance of scalar and vector code. Furthermore, even if SSE interleaves instructions, there are 3 SSE instruction compared to a single AVX. So you mean that three interleaved instruction may outperform a single instruction with the same latency and throughput?

Comment: Not necessarily - just pointing out that your hand-coded SIMD loop is way less efficient than the compiler-generated scalar code, as it spends a lot of time stalled.

Comment: @PaulR, there's nothing that I've hand coded, just one uses __m256d and built-in addition intrinsic and the other uses double[3], without any explicit assembly, yet anyway thanks.

Comment: By hand-coded I just mean that you've used explicit SIMD data types (I assumed you had used intrinsics until you posted the actual code).

Comment: @PaulR, That's alright. It's probably another problem, that I can't even fall back to scalar version with __m256d. But there **is** a performance boost with decent and careful loop unrolling and breaking dependency with AVX, so I don't really want to get rid of __m256d...

Comment: If you want to achieve best possible performance (i.e. If this is not just an academic exercise) then I would suggest posting a more complete scalar version of the code that you want to optimise in a new question and see what the SO SIMD hivemind can do with it.

Comment: @YiFei, I can not see the SSE code here you might talk about AVX VEX.128! BTW your implementation could have been better to perform your task. I can not understand the codes here. But be sure about this point : when you vectorize something loop counter might change. OR please add comparable assembly code here. For example add the inner loop completely. containing loop counters

Comment: @FackedDeveloper Is it? To my understanding, I think SSE up to 4 provide 128bit as its largest and AVX further extend on 256 and 512, whereas VEX is only a encoding. Would you give me more reference on that? The full assembly is posted. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @YiFei, yes it is. VEX is an encoding for compatibility issue. it employs AVX syntax for SSE-SSE4.2. For Example, vaddsd is AVX and VEX encoded but addsd is SSE2. see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086366/how-to-increment-a-vector-in-avx-avx2) there are more references there.

Comment: If you want to see the SSE code you should not use `march=native` because compiler generates code for your platform. if you wanted to see `-msse4.2` is enough and this does not let the compiler generate AVX codes. but you should address a penalty if accrued

Comment: @FackedDeveloper, does that mean that vaddsd and addsd are different instructions even if I don't switch? (that's so-called legacy SSE isn't it?) which is important since Agner only have info for `addsd`.

Comment: @YiFei, no if there was difference anger mentioned. for some instruction such as `vdivps` and `divps` there is and anger separated them

Comment: In my programs there are no differences, however, sometimes I got better performance for non-VEX but the penalty should be addressed. If there aren't some differences between vex-encoded and non-vex the anger fog presents non-vex

Comment: @FackedDeveloper Aha, so other part of your program use also legacy SSE only? I found that libm on my computer are compiled with legacy, so that I experience up to 2x slow down compared to self implemented one (so major part because of inlining maybe).

Comment: I'm working on SIMDization for a year If you see my questions you will realize more. a user ADMS is my past account that is blocked. if you find it see the questions too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136806/discussion-between-facked-developer-and-yifei).